# How to use Jackson to deserialize an array of objects when we have written custom deserializer

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

i have written one custom deserializer , which will take the string and deserialize it 
     public static class MyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer {

```
  @Override
  public MyClass deserialize(JsonParser parser,
                                DeserializationContext deserializer) throws IOException {
            Myclass obj = new Myclass();
            while(!parser.isClosed()) {

            JsonToken jsonToken = parser.nextToken();

            if (JsonToken.FIELD_NAME.equals(jsonToken)) {

                String fieldName = parser.getCurrentName();
                System.out.println(fieldName);
                jsonToken = parser.nextToken();

                switch(fieldName) { 
                -----set the fields of obj
                }
               }
            return obj
          }
```

This can serialize one object at a time , i want to create a list of objects

tried this

```
    JavaType mapType = MAPPER.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Myclass.class);
    List <MyClass> mylist = (List<MyClass>)MAPPER.readValue(jsonString,mapType);
```

This is not working and no error is thrown , just stuck while deserializing it
Do we need to split json array and call deserializer for every object or modify the custom deserializer to create list of objects

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I do not get why there is a need for a custom deserializer at all.

IMHO you could just do:

```
List <MyClass> mylist = MAPPER.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<MyClass>>() {});
```

Comment: because string coming from frontend is different than backend database object

Comment: Ah then you have obviously two different data representations... one view mode and one database model. Separate these concerns in two data classes.

Comment: if two classes are maintained then array of strings can be desrialized into view objects , but i want it to be database object

Comment: Honestly I really do not get the point what you're struggling with. :-/